# Is there a way to get the nodes whose child value is not equal to another child axis?

Tags: xpath

I have this XML and I'm trying to get all of the `/root/ecommerce/cart/product` whose branduid child is not present in `/root/ecommerce/promo/promobrands/promobrand/branduid` values.

```
<root>
    <ecommerce>
        <cart>
            <product>
                <branduid>value1</branduid>
            </product>
            <product>
                <branduid>value2</branduid>
            </product>
            <product>
                <branduid>value3</branduid>
            </product>
            <product>
                <branduid>value4</branduid>
            </product>
        </cart>
        <promo>
            <promobrands>
                <promobrand>
                    <branduid>value1</branduid>
                </promobrand>
                <promobrand>
                    <branduid>value3</branduid>
                </promobrand>
            </promobrands>
        </promo>
    </ecommerce>
</root>
```

So I only have to get the `/root/ecommerce/product` nodes whose branduid values are `value2` and `value4`.
Is there a way in XPath to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below `XPath` expression and let me know the result

```
//cart/product[branduid[not(text()=//promobrand/branduid/text())]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xpath 2.0 , below expression is a straightforward way to achieve:

`//branduid except //promobrand/branduid`

otherwise Andersson's answer is good.